# Spring mvc RedirectAttributes thews exception. How to fix?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 4.0.3.

My controller as follows:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer id,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws ShopNotFound {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("userIndex");       
    userDao.delete(id);;
    String message = "The user was successfully deleted.";
    return mav;
}
```

If I change my code as follows then it works as expected:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer id) throws ShopNotFound {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("userIndex");       
    userDao.delete(id);;
    String message = "The user was successfully deleted.";
    return mav;
}
```

So all my code is fine except RedirectAttributes. I read about it and found code exmple as well. But still I couldn't make it work in my test code. Pleas inform me what is wrong.

Excepiton:-

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.fnx.reg.controller.UserController.deleteUser(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes) throws com.fnx.reg.exception.ShopNotFound]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.

Comment: use the redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "User Deleted Successfully."); I hope it may help u :)

Answer (score 0):

Because of your method return type is using ModelandView.
Refer below 2 link for this issues.

```
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9418

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8968
```